# libGDX android studio find a file

Tags: android, android-studio, configuration, libgdx, galaxy

i am using libGDx in my android studio project.
i kept a file in my phone in 'phone' dir and 'sdcard' dir(galaxy S7)
im trying to open this text file but nothing seems to works.
i want to read the data from this file from my project.

```
    String extRoot = Gdx.files.getExternalStoragePath();
    String locRoot = Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath();
    FileHandle file = new FileHandle(extRoot + "/configSever.txt" );
    FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.absolute("/Phone/configSever.txt");
    boolean exists = Gdx.files.absolute("/Phone/configSever.txt").exists();
    boolean exists1 = Gdx.files.external("../configSever.txt").exists();
    boolean exists2 = Gdx.files.absolute("../configSever.txt").exists();

    this.text=handle.readString();
    String[] netArr;
    // check if the file is exist.
    if (this.dataFile.exists()) {
        this.text = this.dataFile.readString();
```

Comment: the code looks incomplete!

Comment: sure its incomplete. nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the permission to read external storage in your manifest file if you are targeting Android SDK<23 else take permission at run-time.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Put your file in file system.

```
FileHandle fileHandle=Gdx.files.external("xyz.txt");
System.out.println("File Contains :"+fileHandle.readString());
```

Comment: how to take permission at runtime? and where is the file system located on my phone?

Comment: i found out that this line:<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
was already exists in my manifest file so i neet something else.

the external path is /storage/emulated/0/
which my file is not there!